# SQL Server incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'

Tags: php, sql-server-2008

The Error code is:  [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'order'. ) )

```
$tsql = "INSERT INTO dbo.order(client,
contact,
vendor,
iteminfo,
ourcost,
ourshipping,
pricequote,
shipquote,
shipinfo,
requestor)
  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

$params = array(&$_POST['client'],
&$_POST['contact'],
&$_POST['vendor'],
&$_POST['iteminfo'],
&$_POST['ourcost'],
&$_POST['ourshipping'],
&$_POST['pricequote'],
&$_POST['shipquote'],
&$_POST['shipinfo'],
&$_POST['requestor']);
```

This is just about identical to another table I've got and it works just fine.  What am I missing here?

Comment: `order` is a reserved word put it in []'s `INSERT INTO dbo.[order](client,`  or change the name of the table to not use keywords.

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick.

Comment: @xQbert Could you please post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Sure, I'm still trying to get used to the format of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

order is a reserved word put it in []'s `INSERT INTO dbo.[order](client,` or change the name of the table to not use keywords